# Triangle forming probability for area

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-geometry

Say you have a stick which breaks randomly into three pieces (we can choose the points randomly). What is the probability that the area is greater than or equal to $0.4$?

I can see it has something to do with Heron's formula but I just can't put t together.

Comment: what's the length of the stick?

Comment: Hint: Let $X_1,X_2$ be the random points on a unit length stick with $X_2 \geq X_1$ and $X_i$ being iid with distribution $U(0,1)$ and apply Heron's Formula.

Comment: All three sticks share the same distribution. My intuition says find that first.

Comment: Simulation suggests about $0.26$ for the conditional probability and that the expected value of the area is about $0.0299$, assuming the length of the stick is $1$

Comment: I get conditional probability = $\displaystyle\;4\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{x^2(1-x^2)^2 - 0.32^2} dx \approx 0.2586458\;$ where $a \approx 0.37111$, $b \approx 0.76139$ are the two roots of polynomial $x(1-x^2) - 0.32$ in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @achillehui: I think it might help if you explain how $0.04$ becomes $0.32$

Comment: @amWhy: it is a duplicate, but the earlier question (from the same person) does not have a response

Comment: @Henry A person who re-asks the same question they've already posted has posted a duplicate post, and it doesn't matter that the earlier question received no answers.  **Do not repost a question you've already posted**, period. It is true that if someoneasks a question already asked by someone **else,** and  if there is no upvoted answer to the someone else's post, then we cannot close the new post as a duplicate.  (That's the bottom line, **Do not repost a question you've already asked.   Reposting is **not an option**.

Comment: When this question has an answer, closing this as a duplicate to a question without answer (even from same user) server no useful purposes. A better choice is ask the OP to delete the old question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will assume the length of the stick is $1$ and 
we break the stick by picking two points $u, v$ uniformly and independently from $(0,1)$.

Let $a = \min(u,v)$, $b = 1 - \max(u,v)$ and $c = |u-v| = 1 - a - b$.  $a, b, c$ forms the sides of a triangle when and only when

$$a \le b+c,\;b \le c+a,\;c \le a+b\;\iff\;a \le \frac12,\;b \le \frac12,\;a+b \ge \frac12$$

Change variable to $x = 1-2a, y = 1-2b$, the lengths $a,b,c$ forms a triangle when $(x,y)$ falls inside another triangle 
$$\Delta = \big\{ (x,y) : x \ge 0, y \ge 0, x+y \le 1 \big\}$$
with area $\frac12$. It is clear conditional to $a,b,c$ forming a triangle, the probability "density" of picking a particular $(x,y)$ is $2dxdy$.

Let $A$ be the area of a triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and $A_0 = 0.04$.
By [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula), we have

$$\begin{align}
          A &= \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\\
\iff  16A^2 & = 1(1-2a)(1-2b)(1-2c) = xy(1-x-y)\\
\iff  64A^2 & = ((x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2)(1-x-y)
\end{align}
$$
Change variable once again to $p = (x+y), q = (x-y)$, the triangle $\Delta$ becomes

$$\Delta' = \big\{ (p,q) : 0 \le |q| \le p \le 1 \big\}$$

Furthermore,

$$A \ge A_0 
\quad\iff\quad
(p^2 - q^2)(1-p) \ge (8A_0)^2
\quad\iff\quad q^2 \le p^2 - \frac{(8A_0)^2}{1-p}
$$
Let $\displaystyle\;f(p) = \sqrt{p^2 - \frac{(8A_0)^2}{1-p}}\;$ 
and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ be the two roots of $f(p)$ in $(0,1)$. The condition above is equivalent to $\lambda_1 \le p \le \lambda_2$ and $|q| \le f(p)$. 
Since $dpdq = 2dxdy$, the probability we seek equals to

$$\mathbb{P}[A\ge A_0] = \int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} \int_{-f(p)}^{f(p)} dqdp = 2\int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} f(p) dp$$

Change variable to $t = \sqrt{1-p}$, this becomes

$$\mathbb{P}[A\ge A_0] = 4\int_{\mu_1}^{\mu_2} \sqrt{t^2(1-t^2)^2 - (8A_0)^2} dt\tag{*1}$$

where $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are now the roots of the polynomial $\;t(1-t^2) - 8A_0\;$ in $(0,1)$.

For the problem at hand where $A_0 = 0.04$, we have

$$\mu_1 \approx 0.3711104191979701,\; \mu_2 \approx 0.7613913530813122$$
and $(*1)$ evaluates numerically to
$$\mathbb{P}[A\ge A_0] \approx 0.2586458039398669$$
This is compatible with what another user @Henry obtained through simulation.

Comment: Superb!! (+1).  I tried in these lines and confirmed my approach through your answer

Comment: @achillehui What numerical procedure did you follow to compute $(*1)$? My answer is coming out to be $\approx 0.249004$ which is different from our answer. I am trying to understand the reason behind the difference in the error.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 I have asked two CAS (maxima and WA) to compute the integral numerically and they return same number (upto last two digits, the difference most likely caused by rounding error on maxima).

Comment: @achillehui Can you please check this: Let $E$ be the event that three pieces form a triangle, then, $P(E) = 0.25$ and 

$P(A\geq0) = P(A\geq0|E)P(E) + P(A\geq0|E^C)P(E^C) = P(A\geq0|E)0.25 + 0 = 1 \cdot 0.25 = 0.25$

So how can $P(A\geq 0.04) > 0.25$ be true? Am I doing some mistake.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 the probability we are computing is the probability condition to  three sticks forming a triangle. It is 4 times of that probability if we include events where triangle inequalities are violated. $\mathbb{P}[A > 0]$, or more precisely $\mathbb{P}[ A > 0 : \text{ forms a triangle } ]$, equals to $1$. There is no a prior reason for $P(A \ge 0.04 ) \le 0.25$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the length of stick is $2$. Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be randomly sampled from $\text{Uniform}(0,2)$ and let $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}$ be the order statistic.

The length of the three pieces will be,

$$a=X_{(1)},\ \ b=X_{(2)}-X_{(1)},\ \ c=2-X_{(2)}$$

Using,

- triangle inequality ($a+b\geq c, b+c \geq a, c+a\geq b$) and
- the range of $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(2)}$ ($0 \leq X_{(1)} \leq X_{(2)} \leq 2$),

one can obtain the following condition for the three pieces to form a triangle,

$$0 \leq X_{(1)} \leq 1, \ \ 1 \leq X_{(2)} \leq 1+X_{(1)}$$

Using Heron's Formula,

$$A^2 = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c) = 1(1-X_{(1)})(1-X_{(2)}+X_{(1)})(1-2+X_{(2)})$$

$$A^2 = X_{(1)}^2-X_{(2)}^2 +2X_{(2)} +X_{(1)}X_{(2)}^2-X_{(1)}^2X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}X_{(2)}-1$$

Let $E$ be the event that the three pieces form a triangle, then,

$$E = \{0 \leq X_{(1)} \leq 1 \text{ and } 1 \leq X_{(2)} \leq 1+X_{(1)}\}$$

and we need to find,

$$P(A^2 > c) = P(A^2>c|\text{E})P(E) + P(A^2>c|E^C)P(E^C) = P(A^2>c|E)P(E)$$

The joint pdf of $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}$ is given by,

$$f_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)}}(x_1, x_2) = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}, \ \ x_1, x_2 \in [0,2],\ x_1 \leq x_2$$

And therefore the probability of the event $E$ is,

$$P(E) = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{1+X_{(1)}}f_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)}}(x_1, x_2) \partial x_2 \partial x_1 = \frac{1}{4}$$

The conditional joint pdf of $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}$ conditioned on $E$ is,

$$\begin{align} f_{X_{(1)},X_{(2)}|E}(x_1, x_2) &= \frac{f_{X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}}(x_1\mathbb{I}(x_1 \in [0,1]), x_2\mathbb{I}(x_2 \in [1, 1+x_1]))}{P(E)}\\\\ &= \frac{1/2}{1/4} \\\\ &= 2,\ x_1 \in [0,1], x_2 \in [1,1+x_1]\end{align}$$

Introduce two random variables $U$ and $V$ as follows,

$$U = X_{(1)}$$

$$V = A^2 = X_{(1)}^2-X_{(2)}^2 +2X_{(2)} +X_{(1)}X_{(2)}^2-X_{(1)}^2X_{(2)}-X_{(1)}X_{(2)}-1$$

Writing $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(2)}$ in the form of $U$ and $V$,

$$X_{(1)} = U$$

$$X_{(2)}^2(1-U) + X_{(2)}(U^2+U-2)+V+1-U^2=0 \\\\ 
\implies X_{(2)}^2 - X_{(2)}(U+2)-\frac{V+1-U^2}{U-1}=0 \\\\
\implies X_{(2)} = \frac{U+2 \pm\sqrt{(U+2)^2+\frac{4(V+1-U^2)}{U-1}}}{2}$$

Based on the values $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}$ can take so as to form a triangle, we obtain the values that $U$ and $V$ can take,

$$0 \leq U \leq 1, \ \ 1 \leq \frac{U+2 \pm\sqrt{(U+2)^2+\frac{4(V+1-U^2)}{U-1}}}{2} \leq 1+U \\\\ \implies 0 \leq U \leq 1, \ \ 0 \leq V \leq \frac{U^2(1-U)}{4}$$

In order to obtain the pdf of $U, V$ conditioned on $E$, we compute the determinant of the Jacobian of $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}$ with respect to $U, V$ as follows,

$$J = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial X_{(1)}}{\partial U} & \frac{\partial X_{(1)}}{\partial V} \\ \frac{\partial X_{(2)}}{\partial U} & \frac{\partial X_{(2)}}{\partial V} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ \ldots & \frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt{((U+2)(U-1))^2+4(V+1-U^2)(U-1)}}\end{pmatrix} \\ \implies |det J| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{((U+2)(U-1))^2+4(V+1-U^2)(U-1)}}$$

Corresponding to the $\pm$ sign in above matrix, let there be two different matrices $J_+, J_-$. For both matrices, $|det J_{+}| = |det J_{-}| = |det J|$.

Now, we compute the pdf of $U,V$ conditioned on $E$,

$$\begin{align} f_{U,V|E}(u,v) &= f_{X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}|E}\left(u, \frac{u+2 +\sqrt{(u+2)^2+\frac{4(v+1-u^2)}{u-1}}}{2}\right) |det J_{+}| \\\\ & \ \ \ + f_{X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}|E}\left(u, \frac{u+2 -\sqrt{(u+2)^2+\frac{4(v+1-u^2)}{u-1}}}{2}\right) |det J_{-}| \\\\ &= 2 \cdot 2 \cdot |det J| \\\\ &= \frac{4}{\sqrt{((u+2)(u-1))^2+4(v+1-u^2)(u-1)}}\end{align}$$

It is easy to $\color{red}{\text{verify}}$ that,

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\frac{u^2(1-u)}{4}}\frac{4}{\sqrt{((u+2)(u-1))^2+4(v+1-u^2)(u-1)}} \partial v \partial u = \int_{0}^{1} 2u \partial u = 1$$

Integrate over $U$ to obtain the marginal distribution of $V$ conditioned on $E$,

$$f_{V|E}(v) = \int_{u:\ 0 \leq u \leq 1,\ \ 0 \leq v \leq \frac{u^2(1-u)}{4}} f_{U,V|E}(u,v) \partial u$$

The cdf of $V$ conditioned on $E$ will then be,

$$P(V \leq c | E) = \int_{0}^{c}\int_{u:\  0 \leq u \leq 1,\ \  0 \leq v \leq \frac{u^2(1-u)}{4}} f_{U,V|E}(u,v)\partial u \partial v $$

Consider the equation $v = f(u) = \frac{u^2(1-u)}{4}, \ u \in [0,1]$. For a particular value of $v = c > 0$, there are two values of $u$ satisfying the equation. Let those values be $u_0$ and $u_1$.

Note that $u_0 \in [0,f^{-1}(v_{max})] \equiv [0,\frac{2}{3}]$ and $u_1 \in [f^{-1}(v_{max}), 1] \equiv [\frac{2}{3},1]$. With this argument, the above integral can be written as,

$$\begin{align}P(V \leq c | E) &= \int_{0}^{u_0}\int_{0}^{\frac{u^2(1-u)}{4}} f_{U,V|E}(u,v)\partial v \partial u + \int_{u_0}^{u_1}\int_{0}^{c} f_{U,V|E}(u,v) \partial v \partial u \\\\
& \ \ \ \ + \int_{u_1}^{1}\int_{0}^{\frac{u^2(1-u)}{4}} f_{U,V|E}(u,v)\partial v \partial u\\\\
&= \int_{0}^{u_0}2udu + \int_{u_0}^{u_1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{(u-1) (u^3 - u^2 + 4c)}}{u-1} + 2u \right)  \partial u + \int_{u_1}^{1}2u \partial u\\\\
&= u_0^2 + \int_{u_0}^{u_1}\frac{2 \sqrt{(u-1) (u^3 - u^2 + 4c)}}{u-1}  \partial u + u_1^2 - u_0^2 + 1 - u_1^2 \\\\
&= 1 + \int_{u_0}^{u_1}\frac{2 \sqrt{(u-1) (u^3 - u^2 + 4c)}}{u-1}  \partial u \end{align}$$

Finally,

$$\begin{align} P(A^2>c) &= P(A^2 > c|E)P(E) \\\\
&= (1-P(V \leq c|E))P(E) \\\\ 
&= \left(- \int_{u_0}^{u_1}\frac{2 \sqrt{(u-1) (u^3 - u^2 + 4c)}}{u-1}  \partial u \right)P(E) \end{align}$$

Now, the value of $c$ is $0.04^2$ for the case when the length of the stick is $1$. Scaling up this value for the stick of length $2$ so that the probability doesn't change,

$$\frac{c_{new}}{\text{(max area in case of length 2 stick)}^2} = \frac{c_{old}}{\text{(max area in case of length 1 stick)}^2} \\\\ \implies \frac{c_{new}}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{9}\right)^2} = \frac{c_{old}}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{36}\right)^2} \\\\ \implies c_{new} = 0.0256$$

For $c > 0$, the values $u_0$ and $u_1$ are the solutions of $c = \frac{u^2(1-u)}{4}$ in the intervals $[0,\frac{2}{3}]$ and $(\frac{2}{3}, 1]$, respectively. Therefore, for $c = c_{new} = 0.0256$, $u_0 = 0.420283$ and $u_1 = 0.862277$. Putting these values in the last equation,

$$P(A^2 > c_{new} | E) = -\int_{u_0}^{u_1}\frac{2 \sqrt{(u-1) (u^3 - u^2 + 4c_{new})}}{u-1}  \partial u \approx \color{blue}{0.258646}$$

$$P(A^2 > c_{new}) = \frac{-\int_{u_0}^{u_1}\frac{2 \sqrt{(u-1) (u^3 - u^2 + 4c_{new})}}{u-1}  \partial u}{4} = \color{blue}{0.0646615} $$

Note: Used Wolfram to compute the value of the integral.

Comment: It should be compared to $\sqrt 3/9$ when the stick breaks to 3 equal parts.

Comment: I suspect you are supposed to assume the length of the stick is $1$

Comment: @Henry The main ideas will remain same even if the length of the stick is taken to be $2$. I took the length as $2$ so that the semi perimeter becomes $1$. Spent few hours, still couldn't find the closed form solution. I ll try again later.

Comment: I voted up for your try. Good try!!

Comment: @satishramanathan Thanks. I have completed my solution now.